# How to use use a django variable in html <script> tag?

Tags: html, django

Like the python variable has a list of values and I want to equate a variable, say var list= python variable inside  tag.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean but you could try the following:   {% with list=python %}

<script>
    list
    </script>

{% endwith %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable tags in Django are surrounded by `{{` and `}}`and they're replaced with values when the template is evaluated. That being said, you can make use of the Django variables in JavaScript as follow:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var list = "{{djangoVariable}}"
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But Actually I want another help. What changes should I make in views.py to make use of this variable in my html file? It is passed as a dictionary right? But I want it to be passed as a list.

Comment: As for the later question, in your views.py you pass the list as follow: `return render_to_response(your_file.html', {"list": list})` and you make use of that list in your HTML using the Django templating engine as follow: `{% for item in list %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Sorry again, but my output is not the way how I want it to look :( . The python variable holds the contents of a json file. In the .html file, inside the script tag the var list, holds the json contents and the necessary actions will be taken to display it in tabular form. This works if I directly pass the entire file to var list. But it is not working through python variable. :( The json file is getting printed as it is, one below the other and it is not in tabular form. Any ideas?

Comment: According to [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/)  `render_to_response()` has been Deprecated since version 2.0. it's better to use [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render)

Comment: No worries @surreshkummar! So if I get this straight, you want to iterate over the JSON data using JavaScript? if that's the case, I need to have a look at what kind of data you're dealing with to give a coherent answer.

Comment: Yes exactly!! Do you want the code? I don;t want to share it here because it's a company's project. Anywhere else where I can share? Like email id?